# MS Service Manager Portal - app pool account permissions

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, service, manager

Apologies if this is a stupid question, but I've installed the SM Portal following advice on various articles, and they all seem to say to run the portal app pool as the Service Manager service account. This account is also required to be a local admin on the service manager server. Isn't this a bit insecure or am i missing something?

If anyone knows how to run it as another account with less permissions, then that would be great.

Many thanks

Amy

Answer (score 0):

As per the Technet, their is requirement that "Service Manager services account" Must be Domain Admin group as well as local admin.

I dont see the any insure as long as you secure the account and password. Read more here:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh495662.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh495629.aspx

Comment: OK thank you for that - just curious as to why it doesn't seem to fit in with the least permissions model. I guess we'll just tighten the security around it a bit more. Thanks again